# Namo Media SDK unrecognized selector exception for namo_setImageWithURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I'm using the [Namo Media](http://www.namomedia.com/) [SDK](http://docs.namomedia.com/quickstart/) for native ads in my iOS app. In my `setAdData:` callback for my `NAMOAdFormat`, I'm getting this exception:

```
2014-05-14 20:40:43.368 NewsStreamIOS[30861:90b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView namo_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:completed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb154830'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    ...

    4   CoreFoundation       0x020e10ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   NewsStreamIOS        0x0001b701 __92-[NAMOAdData loadIntoImageView:imageURL:imageMetadata:placeholderImage:animation:completed:]_block_invoke + 570
    6   libdispatch.dylib    0x027587b8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
...
)
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I never explicitly call `UIImageView namo_setImageWithURL` which it errors out on.

My `setAdData` method looks like this:

```
- (void)setAdData:(NAMOAdData *)adData {
  [adData loadImageIntoImageView:self.adImageView];
  [adData loadTextIntoLabel:self.adTextLabel];
  [adData loadAdvertiserIconIntoImageView:self.advertiserIconImageView];
  [adData loadAdvertiserNameIntoLabel:self.advertiserNameLabel];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Click on your **Build Settings** and find the **Other Linker Flags** setting.
>   Add -ObjC to both **Debug** and **Release**.

From the [Namo Quick Start Guide](http://docs.namomedia.com/quickstart/ios/uitableview/#step-2-install-the-namo-sdk)